# one django form with two input, two urls, two views, both having different js for following page

Tags: javascript, html, django, forms, django-forms

I have a django form which picks up some user entered text.

Now I want to provide this form two different input types.

forms.py:-

```
from django import forms
from models import blogs

class blogform(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = blogs
        fields = ('text','submitter')
```

In the template (the part where I am confused):-

```
  <form method = "post" action = "<target url comes here>"> {% csrf_token %}
    <div><textarea id="textid" name = "text"></textarea></div>
    <input type = "input1" name="name1" id="id1" value = "value1"/>
    <input type = "input2" name="name2" id="id2" value = "value2"/>
   </form>
```

Both of them should use the same text from textarea, but take the site to different urls and hence different views.

Most related answers on stackoverflow had two input types but were leading to same action url. The same will happen in above snippet as well.

How do I make both inputs go to different urls?

Moreover, the action needs to be independent in such a way that I can use different js for opening new url. For example:- clicking on input type 1 takes to new page on same tab whereas clicking on input type opens new url on a new tab.

Comment: You can always use JavaScript to handle your input (button?) clicks:

Comment: that is what i am planning to do. However I wish I knew a way of doing it using django forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use JavaScript to handle your input (button?) clicks:

```
<input type="button" onclick="this.form.action='target_url_1'; this.form.submit(); return false;" value="Send to 1st url">
<input type="button" onclick="this.form.action='target_url_2'; this.form.submit(); return false;" value="Send to 2nd url">
```